# JsonConvert error CS0433: The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, and 'WebDriver

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Error while serializing the JSON

> JsonConvert        error CS0433: The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I search the solution throughout the stack overflow questions but doesn't find anything. Struggling to get resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you post your code, my friend?

Comment: Try specifying the full description of the class like `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` when you use it and see what happens

Comment: Your app is pulling in multiple different versions of `Newtonsoft.Json` - directly and via other dependencies. You will probably have to use the oldest version of these two in your app. If it's only from dependencies - then you're probably out of luck. With such a big difference in versions there are bound to be some breaking changes between them

Comment: If the type is defined in exactly the same namespace in two different assemblies, then you need to use "extern alias"; one sec, I wrote a long post about that a little while back (goes hunting...); I will say, however, that it is *very* bad form for `WebDriver` to absorb a lib like this - that's really bad etiquette and practice. What is `WebDriver`? (the correct approach would have been for `WebDriver` to declare a transitive dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json`)

Comment: Or your problem is that both of these dependencies declare a JsonConvert class - and probably in the same namespace. Did you write the WebDriver assembly?

Comment: Here you go: [`extern alias`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990900/23354), but again: the "correct" fix here is for `WebDriver` to not do this

Comment: Which Webdriver did you install, and how? Is it a NuGet package? Or did you ILMerge some stuff?

Comment: @CodeCaster it looks like `Selenium.WebDriver` does an il-merge in the [BUILD.bazel](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/BUILD.bazel), absorbing Newtonsoft.Json into it; that's... just really nasty behavior

Comment: @CodeCaster it's NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks all! I don't see error now when I use using NewtonsoftJsonAlias = Newtonsoft.Json; but I feel this is not solution because for each class I need to define Alias.